# openssl s_client works with IP, but does nothing with domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, openssl

I recently-ish set up an internal (firewalled) apache2 web server that exactly one of my colleagues cannot reach for some reason (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR, indicating something's wrong with the handshake/SSL/ciphers). Since I don't have a sufficiently clear idea of the underlying problem there, I'm not aiming to solve his unspecific problem with this question. *But:*

While trying to understand the issue behind his problems, I noticed the following odd behavior:
If I run

```
openssl s_client -connect 111.222.333.111:443
```

with the **IP address**, then I can test all of the ciphers etc. as expected.
The connection is established basically instantaneously, everything seems fine.
But if I do the same with

```
openssl s_client -connect my_domainname.com:443
```

i.e., with the registered **domain name**, then simply nothing seems to happen, `openssl-s_client` doesn't never returns (as if it were still trying to establish a connection forever?) and I cannot get it to give me any output whatsoever.
However, opening `my_domainname.com` in a browser works as expected for everyone except that one colleague, and `ping`, `dig`, `nmap` etc. also correctly resolve the domain name.
Conversely,

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
```

*does* work, so it seems I've misconfigured something? Or might something be going wrong with `openssl`'s DNS resolution?

Comment: Well, it looks like you still have some problem with your DNS, either your local DNS resolver or with the domain. Debugging such domain problems *requires* disclosure, so won't you mind sharing the real domain name that shows these strange symptoms?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for the hint, after messing about with the DNS I figured out it was mostly my own fault for not opening the IPv6 ports despite the IPv6 address being served as a DNS reply, see my answer below if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, which might not be relevant to many other people, but it was indeed the issue in my specific case:

### The problem

`openssl s_client`, apparently by default (?), requests both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from DNS nameservers and then apparently tries to connect **only via IPv6** if it gets a valid response to the IPv6 DNS request.
The problem was that I had not opened the IPv6 HTTP(S) ports, so `openssl` was requesting an IPv6 address from DNS servers, getting a valid response and valid IPv6, then attempting to connect to that IPv6 address and getting blocked by the firewall.

Other programs such as `nmap` and Firefox were evidently either using IPv4 by default or falling back to IPv4 after noticing that IPv6 was failing, hence why I couldn't detect the issue at first.

### How to detect it

If it helps someone else:
I figured out that this was the issue by listening for TCP traffic on port 53 (DNS):

```
sudo tcpdump -n port 53
```

where I noticed the following exchange following my execution of `openssl s_client`:

```
18:24:57.649939 IP local-ip.50643 > dns-server.53: 12404+ [1au] A? domain-name.com. (55)
18:24:57.650293 IP local-ip.39731 > dns-server.53: 26725+ [1au] AAAA? domain-name.com. (55)
18:24:57.651843 IP dns-server.53 > local-ip.50643: 12404* 2/0/1 CNAME cname-of-server., A server-ipv4-address (146)
18:24:57.651877 IP dns-server.53 > local-ip.39731: 26725* 2/0/1 CNAME cname-of-server., AAAA server-ipv6-address (158)
```

indicating that `openssl` had requested and subsequently received both IPv4 (`A`) and IPv6 (`AAAA`) DNS questions and answers.
(Here and in the following, `local-ip`, `dns-server`, `cname-of-server`, `server-ipv6-address` and `server-ipv4-address` are placeholders and not literal.)

Then I checked for traffic to and from the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses that were given as replies to the DNS query:

```
sudo tcpdump host server-ipv6-address # in one tab
sudo tcpdump host server-ipv4-address # in another tab
```

right before running the `openssl s_client` command.
I noticed that there were unanswered session establishment (SYN, `[S]` in `tcpdump` output) packets for the IPv6 host, but nothing on IPv4, indicating that `openssl` was ignoring the IPv4 address that it received and trying to connect using only the IPv6 answer.

### It works if you fix it

After I changed the firewall settings of the server to allow incoming IPv6 HTTP(S) packets, `openssl s_client` was able to successfully connect and `tcpdump` showed normal handshakes taking place with the IPv6 host. Side note: Firefox automatically switched to IPv6 after the ports were opened.

Comment: You can also set precedence of IPv4 higher than IPv6 in glibc-based Linux DNS resolver by adding a line similar to `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` into `/etc/gai.conf`. Probably there is similar mechanism for systemd resolver, too.

Comment: That probably also would have solved the problem, though I think it's clear that it is preferable to not have misconfigured IPv6. Ideally, `openssl s_client` could have switched to IPv4 after IPv6 timed out and informed me of the IPv6 timeout, but I couldn't find a way to make it do that.

Comment: ...in other words, `openssl s_client` could implement [RFC8305](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8305) or some variant of it.